# Function call within a function not working

Tags: javascript, html, function, call

I have a function I call to initialize a page :

```
function initialize_selections() {
var freeamountElement = document.getElementById("text-freeamount");
var dlyElement = document.getElementById("text-dly");
var freeshipperElement = document.getElementById("text-freeshipper");
if(freeamountElement){
  var shippingMethod = document.getElementById("text-freeamount").innerText;
  document.getElementById('radio-freeamount').checked = true;
  document.getElementById('value-shipping').innerHTML = '$0.00';
  document.getElementById('text-shipping').innerHTML = shippingMethod;
  
}else if(dlyElement){
  var shippingMethod = document.getElementById("text-dly").innerText;
  document.getElementById('radio-dly').checked = true;
  document.getElementById('value-shipping').innerHTML = '$0.00';
  document.getElementById('text-shipping').innerHTML = shippingMethod;
}else if(freeshipperElement){
  var shippingMethod = document.getElementById("text-freeshipper").innerText;
  document.getElementById('radio-freeshipper').checked = true;
  document.getElementById('value-shipping').innerHTML = '$0.00';
  document.getElementById('text-shipping').innerHTML = shippingMethod;
}else{
  var shippingMethod = document.getElementById("text-upsxml").innerText;
  var shippingValue = document.getElementById("value-upsxml").innerText;
  document.getElementById('radio-upsxml').checked = true;
  document.getElementById('value-shipping').innerHTML = shippingValue;
  document.getElementById('text-shipping').innerHTML = shippingMethod;  
}
// myPoints();
};
```

This is working well on initial page load.  Depending on specfic conditions I want to call it again, from a separate function:

```
function hideForm(){
if (document.getElementById('thebox').checked==true){
  document.getElementById('formdiv').style.display="block";
  document.getElementById('formdiv2').style.display="none";
  document.getElementById('formdiv3').style.display="block";
  var shipping_method = 'Pick Up Your Order';
  document.getElementById('text-shipping').innerHTML = shipping_method ;
  document.getElementById('value-shipping').innerHTML = '$0.00';
  document.querySelector('input[name="shipping"]:checked').checked = false;
//  myPoints();

} else {
  document.getElementById('formdiv').style.display="none";
  document.getElementById('formdiv2').style.display="block";
  document.getElementById('formdiv3').style.display="none";
  var shipping_method = document.getElementById('text-upsxml').innerText;
  document.getElementById('text-shipping').innerHTML = shipping_method ;
  var shipping_value = document.getElementById('value-upsxml').innerText;
  document.getElementById('value-shipping').innerHTML = shipping_value;
  document.querySelector('input[name="shipping"]:checked').checked = false;
  document.querySelector('input[name="payment"]:checked').checked = false;
  initialize_selections();
};
};
```

Both codes work well and do as I am looking for except that I can not call initialize_selections from hideForm (same thing occurs with the myPoints function, but commented it out to isolate the issue.

Comment: Are the functions in the same file? Do hideForm() find initialize_selections()?

Comment: both functions are in the same file, I have gotten part of it to work, so I will trace though it, I believe it has to do with globals and scope.  thanks